# Not able to assign values and error while converting system.collection.objectmodel.observation to generic list

Tags: c#, wcf

```
proxy.loginCompleted += new EventHandler<loginCompletedEventArgs>(loginfn);
proxy.loginAsync(username,password1);
void loginfn(object sender, loginCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result.Count!=0)
    {
        System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<customer> temp = e.Result;
        foreach (var item in temp)
        {
           Guid companyrefid = item.companyrefid;
           int id = item.id;
        }
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/customernames.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

in wcf :

```
public List<customer> login(string salesmanname, string usercode)//i am getting values in this
```

Comment: what is the result type?

Comment: list which comes from wcf

Comment: Change `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<customer> temp` to `var temp` and forget about type problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way to initialize `ObservableCollection<T>` from `List<T>` :

```
ObservableCollection<customer> temp = new ObservableCollection<customer>(e.Result);
```